# Responsive HTML5 Canvas Using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that draw an image on it.
If I set the canvas size by css in % then the image comes out very blurry.
If I set it in pixels then the image is drawn fine.

```
#myCanvas{
    border:1px dotted black;
    width:100%;
}
img{
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
}
```

```
<canvas id="myCanvas">Your Phone is Not Compatible With the APP.</canvas>
<p></p>
<img src="http://www.artlimited.net/user/0/0/1/4/9/7/9/artlimited_img175960.jpg">
```

```
$("document").ready(function(){    
    function drawcanvas(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src ="http://www.artlimited.net/user/0/0/1/4/9/7/9/artlimited_img175960.jpg";
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
            document.querySelector("p").innerHTML="canvas height="+context.canvas.height+"canvas width="+context.canvas.height;     
        };
    }
    drawcanvas();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/vvu6myy6/7/

Comment: I need to improve the resolution of the image as u see its very bad

Comment: set the width and height of the canvas using js. canvas element won't consider % value while drawing..The width attribute defaults to 300, and the height attribute defaults to 150..

Comment: PS: Set `src` after the `onload` function, also you can use `canvas.width` instead of `context.canvas.width`.

Answer (score 0):

Try translating your context by half a pixel:

```
context.translate(0.5, 0.5);
```

then give the canvas % width again. It should stop showing blurry image.

This is a common method to disable canvas antialiasing (which I think is the cause of the blurry image)

Comment: translate or no translate you cannot expect an 400x400 image to automagically look awesome on 800x800. It's look blurry in either cases.